# Is it possible to look up all name alias of a given type (e.g. "int" versus "Int32")?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, reflection, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've been writing unit tests to verify the validity of MVC routes. For example,

```
[Route("foo/bar/{id:int}")]
public IHttpActionResult SomeAction(int id)
{
   // ... 
}
```

would be valid but

```
[Route("foo/bar/{id:List<string>}")]
public IHttpActionResult SomeAction(int id)
{
   // ... 
}
```

or

```
[Route("foo/bar/{buzz:int}")]
public IHttpActionResult SomeAction(int id)
{
   // ... 
}
```

wouldn't.

But the problem is that I'm getting false negatives because, in the first example above, when I check that `{int:id}` in the route matches a parameter in the action method, the name of the type in the parameter is `Int32` via reflection and I don't know how to make my test know that `Int32` is the same as `int`. Is there a way?

Comment: That is 100% certain not the issue at hand. You need to dig deeper.

Comment: You are making an incorrect assumption about what `int` means in the routing configuration. `int` is the name of a [route constraint](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/#route-constraints), it has nothing at all to do with the C# meaning of the `int` datatype (with alias `System.Int32`). Besides, you should be [testing your routing config](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/07/testing-routing-and-url-generation-in-aspnet-mvc.html), not testing to see if the MVC framework works (you should assume it is already tested).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you are writing those unit tests in order to ensure that the routing you configured is on a suitable method and to make sure that on any signature change your test suit will force you to change the routing constraint too.

Therefore I'm assuming that your first method is actually working, and the only problem you are having is with the `if("int" == parameterType.Name)` that is written somewhere on your test method.

Since you want your test to know that a "int" and a "Int32" are the same, you will need a list of those alias. It can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx). This list contains the class name from the .Net Framework as well the C# built-in alias. Just create and populate a dictionary and check based on that. Yes, you will have to manually type those pairs.

Just remember that some of the routing constraints are not simply a datatype (for example max or length), but you can just test them against the correspondent datatype too (on the example, int and string).